# Facebook Api search users by name returning empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used this url with access token https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Marcus&type=user&access_token= and it returns empty data `data    []`

Settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt8tc.png

I was trying to get a list of users with their name using javascript. Is it possible ?

Comment: No that is not possible anymore

Comment: I think Facebook removed the ability to do this

Answer (score 3):

as mentioned in the comments here is the official Facebook note, that you cannot search for `type = user` anymore:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Answer (score 0):

The /search endpoint for pages, videos, groups and events has been disabled by facebook after the cambridge analytica scandal.

Faceboook Changelog:

You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object types:

event
group
page
user

Comment: duplicate answer